Finding determinant from given relation

$A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices
$$A^{-1}B + B^{-1}A= -I,$$
where $I$ is an identity matrix.
$$|A| = 3$$
$$|B| =\, ? ,$$
where $|A|$ denotes the determinant of matrix $A$.

My try:
$$ A^{-1}B +I = -B^{-1}A$$
Taking determinant
$$|A+B| = -|A|^{2}/|B|$$
By multiplying and diving by determinant A . Now I'm stuck, any hints would help a lot

Equivalent formulation here.

Multiplying by $A$ on the left and $B^{-1}$ on the right gives
$$
I + X + X^2 = 0,
$$
where $X = AB^{-1}$. Multiplying by $I-X$, gives
$$
I-X^3 = 0,
$$
Therefore, $(AB^{-1})^3 = I$, which implies $|B| = \omega^k |A|$ where $\omega$ is the third root of unity and $k=0,1,2$. Assuming these are real matrices, we get $|B|=|A| = 3$.

See the reference I gave above.
